# sql statement for wordpress query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, mysql-workbench, database-table

im trying to extract the following fields from a local wordpress installation

- post_title
- image_url
- post_excerpt

other criteria for the SELECT is:

1. the status is **publish**
2. it's a **post** item
3. and the results only come from the *projects* parent category or **any** subcategory of **project**

i've got this far already but am finding it difficult to workout the rest

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy, wp_postmeta
WHERE wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
AND post_status = 'publish'
AND post_type = 'post'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'image_url'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.parent = 5
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

as per the below *comment*, table for **wp_term_taxonomy** is:
term_taxonomy_id || term_id || taxonomy || description || parent || count

as per the below *comment*, table for **wp_posts** is:
ID || post_author || post_date || post_content || post_title|| post_excerpt || post_status 
*there are more, but not relevant here*

as per the below *comment*, table for **wp_term_relationships** is:
object_id ||term_taxonomy_id || term_order

as per the below *comment*, table for **wp_postmeta** is:
meta_id || post_id || meta_key || meta_value

Comment: would you mind sharing with those who don't have the wordpress tables memorized the table names and columns? We can then help you much easier :)

Comment: sorry, thats the majority of my problem. im not sure how to get a list of the categories, nor the subs :/

Comment: You only provided the one table D=... Really wanted to help you man :(. I need to know all the tables involved. If I know that I can likely help much more!

Comment: as per request, hope this helps you help me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to use the functions provided by WordPress to fulfill the requirements. Yes, the images( image urls ) are stored inside wp_posts table as attachments.

```
<?php
$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'attachment', 
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'numberposts' => -1, 
'post_status' => null, 
'post_parent' => $post->ID 
); 
$attached_images = get_posts( $args );
?>
```

use this wordpress function to get post image url pass the post id to function it result the url of image. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url

```
wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
```

However, if you want to go against something that is built in, you can try the following, however I must say I have no local version of wordpress to test against at the moment.

`SELECT  p.post_title as post_title, p.post_excerpt as post_excerpt,( SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE id = m.meta_value ) AS url 
FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta m
WHERE p.post_type =  'post'
AND p.post_status =  'publish'
AND p.id = m.post_id
AND m.meta_key =  '_thumbnail_id'`

Let me know if you need anything more and I will install a local wordpress installation and do it with you through a chat session.

Comment: Many thanks, I look forward to putting this I to practice on Monday

Comment: No problem, I hope it helps you out. If you are satisfied with it on Monday please don't forget to upvote/accept the answer :) Best of luck!

Comment: The latter option is perfect thank you. For the php snippet I'd have to convert my page to php, which wouldn't be consistent. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad you finally got around to trying it out and it working. Best of luck for any future problems :)